# Expected value of objects with a serial number greater than a given number

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have $n$ objects, numbered $1$ to $n$. If I take out $m$ objects randomly, then what is the expected value of the number of objects whose serial number is greater than to $x$? $ (1 \le x \le n) $

**EDIT 1:** Here's my best attempt. If I denote the probability that exactly $i$ objects have a serial number greater than $x$ as $p(i)$, then the expected value is $\sum_{i=1}^{n} ip(i)$

There are $x$ objects whose serial number is not greater than $x$ and $n-x$ objects whose is. Therefore the probability that exactly $i$ objects have a serial number greater than $x$ is.... I'm not sure. I'm guessing $$ \frac{\binom{x}{m-i} \binom{n-x}{i}}{\binom{n}{m}} $$

I don't know if this is correct or whether this sum has a closed form

Comment: I think you should include your own attempt to solve the problem in the post. It can be anything e.g. your ideas, what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: I don't know how to even start this. This is not from any course I'm taking, but something I encountered while doing a project of my own, so I don't exactly know the tools to solve it. Still, I'll include my best attempt at it

Comment: That's ok, when you include more information, other users can see how much you understand about the topic and can adjust their answer accordingly.

Comment: "Without Loss Of generality", you can assume that the serial numbers are plainly $1,2,...n$...

Comment: If you must only find expectation then it is advisable to check: can I find it without making use of distribution? Expectations are in many cases much easyer to find than the probabilities that go along with a distribution.

Answer (score 5):

Number the objects that are taken out.

For $i=1,\dots,m$ let $X_i$ be a random variable taking value $1$ if the object with label $i$ has serial number greater than $x$ and let it take value $0$ otherwise.

If $X:=X_1+\cdots+X_m$ then $X$ is the number of objects that has a serial number greater than $x$.

So now calculate its expectation and for that use linearity of expectation and symmetry.

The answer will appear to be surprisingly simple.

Comment: How would I calculate the expectation for this without calculating the probability either way?

Comment: You only have to determine the expectation of the $X_i$. They are all equal so determining $\mathbb EX_1$ is enough already. Further note that $\mathbb EX_1$ is exactly the probability that the object with label $i$ has serial number greater than $x$ so equals $1-\frac{x}{n}$. Now that is the only probability that must be calculated (and you did it yourself already). You really do not need the $p(i)$ that you mention.

Comment: @TheInfiniteOne if you choose $m$ out of $n$, the probability that an object is chosen is simple to compute; $1-\frac{x}{n}$. Multiply with $m$ and you get $m-x\cdot\frac{m}{n}$

Answer (score 2):

**From your answer**

The probability that exactly $i$ objects have higher number than $x$ is given by the following expression

$$
P(i)=\frac{\binom{x}{m-i}\binom{n-x}{i}}{\binom{n}{m}}
$$

**Extend to obtain expected value**

Now we just need to multiply each probability with $i$ and sum for all possible $i$ to obtain expected value

$$
\begin{align}
E&=\sum_{i=0}^{m} i\cdot\frac{\binom{x}{m-i}\binom{n-x}{i}}{\binom{n}{m}}
\\\\
&=\frac{(n-x)\binom{n-1}{m-1}}{\binom{n}{m}}
\\\\
&=(n-x)\frac{m}{n}
\\\\
&=
m-x\cdot\frac{m}{n}
\end{align}
$$

**Some explanations**

Say that you select some object with higher number than $x$, say $i$ of them, then it means you select $m-i$ objects with number less than or equal to $x$. Imagine that in addition to this, you also want to choose one of the selected objects with high number and label it special edition, the number of ways to do this is then given by

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{m}i\cdot\binom{x}{m-i}\binom{n-x}{i}
$$

Which is no other than the numerator in our summand. Another way to do this is to select the special edition object first, then select the rest of $m-1$ objects from remaining $n-1$ objects. The number of ways to do this is

$$
(n-x)\binom{n-1}{m-1}
$$

Two expressions used to count the same number of possibilities, so they must be equal

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{m}i\cdot\binom{x}{m-i}\binom{n-x}{i}
=
(n-x)\binom{n-1}{m-1}
$$

Comment: The expression for the probability is correct, then?

Comment: @TheInfiniteOne yes the expression is correct